# Two morphisms between complexes which are not homotopic but induce the same morphisms of cohomology

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category and $f, g \colon X^\bullet \to Y^\bullet$ be two morphisms of complexes in $\mathcal{A}$. Suppose that the morphisms between cohomology induced from $f$ and $g$ are identical in all degrees. Then, my question is: can we always construct a homotopy between $f$ and $g$? If we can't, what is the counterexample?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the category of abelian groups, we have the following (vertical) chain map between (horizontal) complexes.

\begin{eqnarray*}
0\to \mathbb{Z}/(2)\qquad\\
\downarrow \qquad\,\,\,\,\downarrow 1_{\mathbb{Z}/(2)}\\
\mathbb{Z} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/(2)\qquad
\end{eqnarray*}

For any abelian group $C$, the induced maps on cohomology with coefficients in $C$ are trivial.  However this chain map is not null-homotopic (in fact any map $\mathbb{Z}/(2)\to \mathbb{Z}$ is trivial).

Comment: Your answer is beautiful. 
Is the above chain map equivalent to zero in the derived category D(Ab)?

Comment: @LiangChen I am not sure.  Null-homotopic chain maps are equivalent to zero.  However the above map is not null-homotopic.  More generally, if a chain map factors through an acyclic complex, then it is equivalent to zero in the derived category:  If $C$ is acyclic and $f\colon C\to 0,\,\, g\colon 0\to C$ are the unique chain maps then $fg=1_0$ so $$f^{-1}=f^{-1}1_0=f^{-1}fg=1_Cg$$ and $$0_C=gf=f^{-1}f=1_C.$$  Thus given chain maps $a\colon A\to C,\,\, b\colon C \to B$ we have $$ba=b1_Ca=b0_Ca=0.$$

Comment: Thus $$\begin{array}[ccccccccccccc]
{}\cdots&\to &0&\to & 0&\to&0&\to& \mathbb{Z}/(2)&\to &0&\to&\cdots\\
&&\downarrow &&\downarrow&&\downarrow &&\downarrow 1_{\mathbb{Z}/(2)}&&\downarrow\\
\cdots&\to&0&\to&\mathbb{Z}&\stackrel 2\to&\mathbb{Z}& \twoheadrightarrow &\mathbb{Z}/(2)&\to&0&\to&\cdots
\end{array}$$ is equivalent to zero in the derived category, but not null-homotopic.